# 500 internal server error during deployment of django project in elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my django project in AWS elastic beanstalk. The project is deployed fine but I am getting a 500 internal server error when I go to the url after deployment. I got the following error from error log:

**error log**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=29607): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/DJ/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

**.ebextensions/django.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: DJ/wsgi.py
    StaticFiles: /static/=static/
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you add pythonpath to  the config

Comment: How to find my pythonpath ?